# How is the default font size for a wpf window determined?

Tags: wpf, window, font-size

I understand that in WPF the font size used by a control is determined by the parent control, unless an override is defined.

Given that I don't define a font-size anywhere in my application, I assume that the default font-size is that configured for the top-level Window.

Is this value determined by the system the application is running on (and if so where?); or is it determined by some built-in WPF default value (and if so what is it?)

Comment: Check the return value of `DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(this, FontSizeProperty)`.

Comment: That's helpful, but I guess I should have phrased my question as "where is the default set" rather than "what is it"

Comment: `DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(this, FontSizeProperty).BaseValueSource` will tell you exactly that. Did you even try it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default font size is determined by the `FontSize` dependency property of the `TextElement` class: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextElement.cs,e28640b48d79de57. It defaults to `SystemFonts.MessageFontSize` which has a default value of `12`.

The `Control` base class them adds itself as an owner of this dependency property and defines its own `FontSize` property that can any control can set to a custom value.

Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this: https://blog.davidpadbury.com/2008/08/30/change-the-default-font-of-a-wpf-application/.

Comment: link for blog post not wokring

Comment: Wayback Machine to the rescue!
http://web.archive.org/web/20160806025831/https://blog.davidpadbury.com/2008/08/30/change-the-default-font-of-a-wpf-application/